# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() is not working as expected

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

I am trying to read a pdf created by phantomjs from an html file on the file system. I have done the following.

```
       process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(phantomLocation + scriptLocation + inputFile + " " + destinationFileString);
       process.waitFor();
```

I am specifying phantomLocation, js script location, inputHTML and destinationFileString(pdf to be generated and served).

I am writing the following servlet code to read the pdf generated and and send as response.

```
        InvokePhantom phantom = new InvokePhantom(inputHTMLFileName, destinationFile);
        process.create();//call the above piece of code
                //Set the response headers
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
                String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", attchmentName);
                response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

                //For debugging
                File file = new File(destinationFile);
                System.out.println("destinationFile exists = " + file.exists());

                //Write to outputStream
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(destinationFile);
                outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (writer != null) {
                    writer.close();
                }
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But the pdf file being generated by the `phantomjs` is incomplete. When run from command line `phantomjs` is creating the pdf properly(from the same html). But when called from java code it is not working properly. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you please post complete command that needs to be executed

Comment: @Sanjeev phantomjs script?

Comment: Command created by `phantomLocation + scriptLocation + inputFile + " " + destinationFileString` and how you are executing on command-line

Comment: @Sanjeev D:\Docs\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs.exe D:\Docs\screenshot.js C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\1404368319410330387378284269747.html C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\1404368319410.pdf When run from the command line pdf looks fine but not from java code.

Comment: try to read process's error stream and output stream for possible errors/outs

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Is it possible to get process.getOutputStream() to be written directly to the servlet response outputstream? If it is possible I can avoid creating a file system file and sending that file to response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is you are trying to execute a command with arguments as a single String. You should use [Runtime.exec(String[] comand)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) something like this:

```
String[] cmdArray = new String[]{phantomLocation,scriptLocation,inputFile,destinationFileString};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
process.waitFor();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting exit value -1 with the changes

Comment: Try to read Error Stream/Output Stream of Process to get more insight